# ValueObjects exposing outside domain layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, value-object

As I learned from the DDD rules, you have to change the entity through the aggregate root.

However let's say we have a value object "**Address**".

Is it allowed to do in the AR:
*(I've seen this in the eShopOnContainers by Microsoft*

```
public void SetAddress(Address address) {}
```

Or do we have to do it like this in the AR:

```
public void SetAddress(string street, string zip, ..) 
{
    Address = new Address(street, zip, ..);
}
```

If it's okay to do it like the first example, does this count for entities as well? Can you just expose the entity and create it in the layer above it and then add it through the aggregate root?

For now I always did it like the second example, or used a DTO when I had too much parameters.

Comment: "you have to change the entity through the aggregate root" - just wanted to say: don't think of this as something that you have to do because someone said that is the way, but rather about something that you *want* to do in order to limit the coupling (interconnections) between different parts of the codebase. Just how you put an implementation of an object behind a set of public methods, you can put a group of closely related objects (an aggregate) behind one object (the aggregate root) that acts as a "gateway" to the aggregate, and provides a set of methods to work with it.

Comment: So, an aggregate as a whole provides some functionality, in a sort of encapsulated way, and an aggregate root provides an "API" to the aggregate - a number a functions with inputs and outputs, and the associated types of their return values and parameters. Some of those types will be types from your domain, so `SetAddress(Address address)` is absolutely allowed; in the code that uses the aggregate, this helps you express the logic more directly in terms of domain concepts (as opposed to using a bunch of unstructured primitive types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ValueObjects both options are valid.

Personally I prefer creating ValueObject instances outside of the domain layer and passing them as arguments to methods on the Aggregate root. It’s easier to give feedback if there’s an error in the creation, but others could have different experiences.

For entities things are different. The identity of an entity is only guaranteed to be unique within the context of the Aggregate. While there will be situations where the identity of an entity is globally unique in your entire system, it will not be true for all entities so it’s best to assume they aren’t.

Take for example a PhoneBook Aggregate, that contains a collection of Page entities. When you add an Address value object to the PhoneBook.Add(Address) method, internally the Aggregate could assign the address to a specific Page entity. If you would instead model it like PhoneBook.Add(Page), how would you know which page? That would require to move or copy logic out of the Aggregate, exactly not what you want!

Comment: Valid points, thank you! Cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer is to do all of the [parsing of your inputs](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) from their primitive representations to value objects in your application code, before passing then as arguments to your aggregate root.

> does this count for entities as well?

It's a lot less common for domain entities.  In most cases, we're copying information into the domain model, and the value object pattern is the natural choice for that.  If your domain code needs to copy that information into a domain entity, then the domain code can perform the copy itself.

The case where things can get spooky: when you are copying information into an aggregate that doesn't exist yet - aka "create".  Creation patterns are *weird*, and it isn't unusual to see designs where information is copied directly into a new instance of an entity that will be saved in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The term "entity" is used interchangeably for 2 related things, but the difference is quite important for understanding the concept of aggregate root:

- A piece of a data, persisted is some kind of repository (usually some sort of a database). Let's call it row.
- An in-program representation of said piece of data, the former being merely a (temporary) proxy of the latter. let's call it proxy.

"To change the entity" in the context of the question means to overwrite a row in the repository. This act *usually* employs a proxy but not always. On the other hand, changing a proxy doesn't mean that corresponding row will be changed: it's up to the aggregate root to accept or reject the changes.

Therefore, it does not matter how's the proxy created and changed. What's important is that only an aggregate root can actually commit the changes to the repository. And because a value object in the question is a part of an entity, the same rules apply to it.

---

That said, the *best* practices are slightly stricter.

Firstly, there is a design principle of having no invalid state (e.g. [1](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/), [2](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/), [3](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/)). It suggests that passing domain objects (e.g. the value object in the question) instead of their source values is preferable.

Secondly, there is Anemic Domain Model, which is an anti-pattern. Constructing domain objects outside of DDD layer does not necessarily means that domain objects will be anemic. But, a rich domain object most likely needs dependencies, which are an implementation detail of the DDD layer, therefore constructing domain objects through domain services (factories) is also preferable.